# Grant Tables and Views privileges in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I know how to grant privileges on tables:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table TO person;
```

But I was told to grant privileges to 'person' for all tables and views and I was wondering if the above code also grants privileges for views as well or is there another way to do that?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code also can be used for views and even stored procedures. Commonly you would want access to update data in a table:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table TO person;
```

just SELECT on a view:

```
GRANT SELECT ON view TO person;
```

and EXECUTE on a procedure:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON proc TO person;
```

There is some nuance in that. For instance, you can have updatable views (or views with triggers), and you may choose to assign only select and/or insert access to table.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!